# How to customize c-doc-comment-style to use reStructuredText as documentation comment style?

Tags: emacs, restructuredtext, font-lock, cc-mode

Emacs uses `c-doc-comment-style` to specify the documentation comment style to use in `cc-mode`. I'd like to use reStructuredText, or rst, for documentation comments. There's an `rst-mode` for reStructuredText files, with `rst-font-lock-keywords`, but I can't seem to be able to connect the two.

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to use different styles for different projects, as obviously a lot of projects use `gtkdoc` or `doxygen` styles.

Answer (score 1):

`cc-mode` doesn't have support for reStructuredText, and I don't know any simple way to reuse `rst-mode`'s highlighting in `cc-mode`. I think you'll have to write the appropriate code for `cc-mode` yourself.

The [documentation for `c-doc-comment-style`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Doc-Comments.html) has this to say:

> You can also write your own doc comment fontification support to use with `c-doc-comment-style`: Supply a variable or function `*-font-lock-keywords` where `*` is the name you want to use in `c-doc-comment-style`. If it’s a variable, it’s prepended to `font-lock-keywords`. If it’s a function, it’s called at mode initialization and the result is prepended. [...] It is even possible, to a limited extent, to fontify constructs inside a doc comment with other faces. For an example, see pike autodoc comment style towards the end of `cc-fonts-el`.

You can make up a name like `rstdoc` for use as the value of `c-doc-comment-style` and implement it by defining a couple of variables. [The existing definitions](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/375dac936fcca902874ecfd1c57b713581641725/lisp/progmodes/cc-fonts.el#L3306-L3562), as well as the regexps in `rst-mode`, will probably be useful as a source of examples.

> Furthermore, I'd like to be able to use different styles for different projects

This one is easy. You can set `c-doc-comment-style` as a directory-local or file-local variable. See the commands `add-dir-local-variable` and `add-file-local-variable`.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort put in the answer, it mostly just improves the question, rather than answers it. The question is *how* to reuse the definitions from `rst-mode`, and that's completely left unanswered.